# Ploting loadings PCA vs Wavenumber

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, pca

I have the matrix data

```
Wavenumber 450.000000 451.00000
Sample 1.977876 1.977388 1.976533
Sample2 1.803184 1.802537 1.802181  ...
...
Sample29 1.929462 1.928509 1.927309
```

I removed the first line with the following command to plot the graphs only with the samples, after reading the file csv.

```
s<- as.data.frame(t, nrow.names =1)
s.pca <- prcomp(s[-c(1),], center = TRUE, scale. = TRUE)
sd <- s.pca$sdev
loadings <- s.pca$rotation
rownames(loadings) <- colnames(s)
scores <- s.pca$x
library(ggplot2)
scores=as.data.frame(s.pca$x)
###---Plot Components PC1 and PC2
 p<- ggplot(data = scores, obs.scale = .8, var.scale = 1, show.names=TRUE,   aes(x = PC1, y = PC2, label = rownames(scores)))
 p<- p + geom_hline(yintercept = 0, colour = "gray65")
 p<- p + geom_vline(xintercept = 0, colour = "gray65")
 p<- p + geom_text(colour = "black", alpha = 0.8, size = 4)
 p<- p + ggtitle("PCA plot Samples")
 p<- p + theme(axis.title = element_text(family = "Arial", color="#666666", face="bold", size=16))
 p<- p + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold", color="#993333", size=14,angle=0))
 p<- p + theme(axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", color="#993333", size=14, angle=0))
 p<- p + xlab("PC1")
 p<- p + ylab("PC2")
 print(p)
```

I removed the first line, I wonder how can I make a loadings (PC1 and PC2) vs. Wavenumbers of matrix?

Comment: try reading the hyperSpec package vignettes, IIRC there are great examples in there

Comment: And shameless plug, package `ChemoSpec`, though it used base graphics.  You'd want `plotLoadings`.

Comment: @baptiste I tried using the HyperChem package, but the package is most commonly used for processing infrared data matrix. Another pacocte is ChemoSpec, but this package works with two classes of variables and older who come from different data files. But I need the PCA values to make the graph. Do you have any idea how can I do this?

Comment: The ChemoSpec package, but this package works with two variables classes, which are files of different names. I do not have files belonging to two or more variables.  I will try to use this package.@BryanHanson

Answer (score 1):

Since we don't have your data, here is a simple example using data from the `chemometrics` package.  It is categorical data, but you can extend the example to use wavenumbers as your x coordinate.

```
library("ggplot2")
library("chemometrics")
data(glass)
glass.pca <- prcomp(glass)
loadings <- as.data.frame(glass.pca$rotation)
# add in the element info:
loadings <- data.frame(element = colnames(glass), loadings)
qplot(x = element, y = PC1, data = loadings, main = "Loadings for PC1", xlab = "Compound/Element")
```

Or if you wanted the scores:

```
scores <- as.data.frame(glass.pca$x)
qplot(x = PC1, y = PC2, data = scores, main = "Score Plot")
```

EDIT: Using your data (not in a convenient form, you should learn to use `hyperSpec` or `ChemoSpec`)

```
Wave <- read.csv("matrix.csv", nrows = 1)
Int <- read.csv("matrix.csv", skip = 1)
SampNames <- Int[,1]
Int <- Int[,-1]
Fabio <- prcomp(Int)

scores <- Fabio$x
rownames(scores) <- SampNames
scores <- as.data.frame(scores)
qplot(x = PC1, y = PC2, data = scores, geom = "point")

loadings <- Fabio$rotation
rownames(loadings) <- Wave
loadings <- cbind(wave = unlist(Wave), loadings)
loadings <- as.data.frame(loadings)
qplot(x = wave, y = PC1, data = loadings, geom = "line")
```

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/a1mgkdr7cwymid4/matrix.csv?dl=0 . After merge all files (x, y), I created an array of data that way. With the first line of wavenumbers. @BryanHanson.

Comment: Thanks very much. I try with another packages @BryanHanson.

Comment: Did the code above do what you need in the meantime?

Comment: This working this code. I do not need at this time I am still studying the language r. Thanks @BryanHanson